# How to catch RuntimeExceptions from Executors without blocking?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an executor service that accepts new tasks :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
//stupid example with several parralel tasks
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {   
  try{       
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                
            throw new RuntimeException("foo");
        }
    };
    executor.submit(task);
  }

  catch (ExecutionException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not able to catch any exception thrown by the Runnable, unless I'm doing this :

```
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("############### exception :" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The problem is that future.get() is blocking, so if I 'm not able to run my tasks asynchronously and my tasks will not run in parallel, but sequentially.

I would like to be able to use Java 8 and CompletableFuture but I can't ...
Do you have any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why you just don't send all the tasks to run first and then you collect the results?

Comment: Because in my real project it's not a loop but user actions so tasks are arriving constantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the Runnable is executing on a separate thread, so you must handle its exceptions inside the `run()` method.

If you need to gather all the exceptions for later handling, I would do something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
final List<Exception> exceptions = // a place to put exceptions
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Exception>());
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                throw new RuntimeException("foo");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptions.add(e); // save the exception for later
            }
        }
    };
    executor.submit(task);
}
// wait for all the tasks to finish, then...
for (Exception e: exceptions) {
    // whatever you want to do
}
```

Otherwise, if you just want to get information about each exception as it occurs:

```
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                throw new RuntimeException("foo");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Maybe that last catch should re-throw the exception?

Comment: the intention is just to preserve behavior... if a task fails you don't want to silence it unless you know what you are doing... ultimately it would depend on the nature of those tasks whether it is ok to silence the exception but unless one has more information about the problem I think is best not to silence them.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Thanks but that last catch was only to preserve what OP was apparently doing to catch exceptions thrown by `ExecutorService.submit()`. Looking at that method's documentation, it throws only kinds of RuntimeException, so I removed the extraneous `try..catch`

Comment: I can't wait for all the tasks to finish, because in my real project it's not a loop but user actions so tasks are arriving constantly, so I will just handle my error inside the Runnable,  I guess it's the only way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anything you need to do after the task asynchronously can be added to the task itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {   
    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                
            throw new RuntimeException("foo");
        }
    };
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

or you combine them into one Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but we could make a parent Runnable which will do the work of the actual Runnable. The parent will catch all the exceptions you need to know about. Here is slight convoluted approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
        //stupid example with several parralel tasks
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
          Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {   
                       throw new RuntimeException("foo");

            }
        };
        ParentRunnable t = new ParentRunnable();
        t.setRunnable(task, i);
        executor.submit(t);
        }
    }

    static class ParentRunnable implements Runnable {

        Runnable r;
        int index;
        public void setRunnable(Runnable r, int index){
         this.r = r;    
         this.index = index;
        }
        public void run() {
            try{
                System.out.println("\n" + index + "\n");
                r.run();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```